# which one is more idiomatic, "lower left hand corner" or "bottom left hand corner"?

Tags: word-usage, expressions

[image]

I am trying to point out the location (-2,2), which one is more idiomatic, "lower left hand corner" or "bottom left hand corner"?

Comment: Statistically, ***upper*** and ***lower*** are about twice as likely as ***top*** and ***bottom*** in Ame (they're about equally common in BrE). They're all perfectly idiomatic though, so just use whichever you prefer. And for stylistic reasons, stick to those pairs as given (avoid using both ***upper*** and ***bottom***, for example). Note that you don't need the word ***hand*** at all, so if you're going to have to use several of these constructions you should probably omit that in all cases, in the interests of brevity.

Comment: I would say 'lower left corner'

Comment: @FumbleFingers that would make a good answer

Comment: @Bee: The essence of my comment was "use whichever you prefer" (it's a stylistic choice) - to justify my closevote as "Primarily Opinion-Based".

Comment: Fair enough. I thought that perhaps, in cases where it is unclear that it is opinion based, saying that it is actually opinion based would be a valid answer.

Comment: @Bee: It's not hard to do a couple of Google searches for "upper left corner" and "top left corner" - or for greater accuracy, compare the two using [Google NGrams.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=upper+left+corner%2Ctop+left+corner&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cupper%20left%20corner%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctop%20left%20corner%3B%2Cc0) I assume that the basic principle ***upper*** is to ***lower** as **top** is to **bottom*** (i.e. - these are "matched pairs") is an easily-grasped concept.

Comment: @FumbleFingers thanks for your comments, where is the statistic coming from? google search results with the keywords “lower left hand corner” and “bottom left hand corner”?

Comment: Go to [Google NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/) and enter your different search strings separated by commas. For example: **top left hand corner,upper left hand corner,top left corner,upper left corner**. I repeated the search there with and without the word ***hand*** (because it's not normally included anyway), but the total "address + [parameters" is too long to include in an ELL comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual, this is all about context - if you are talking about an item as clear as that graph, then bottom is more appropriate (if you are indeed referring to the bottom, as opposed to 'near the bottom').

If the context was less clear, such as if there were numerous graphs on the same page, then it might be better to refer to the lower edge/corner as a reference to the bottom might be taken to mean the bottom of the entire page.

In other words, 'bottom' is an absolute position, whereas 'lower' is relative.

Comment: Right, there is no need to say lower hear. The lower and upper house (of government. upper and lower school. Lower is really comparative.